# Laravel queue dispatch() function forgot/not deliver values

Tags: laravel, queue, dispatch

I am trying to dispatch some files to my queue.
The dispatch() function is not working all around my stuff - for Example:

`$auth = Auth::user();`
`$name = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();`
just give me a null, when `DD($...);` ?!

`$userid = User::find(1);` (by hitting the users id..) works fine!
can someone explain why that dispatch() function is not working for me?

the job code:
`
class File_Upload implements ShouldQueue
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

```
protected $directory;
protected $uploadDataName;
protected $inputFormName;
protected $request;


public function __construct( $directory, $uploadDataName, $inputFormName )
{
    //$this->$request = $request;
    $this->directory = $directory;
    $this->uploadDataName = $uploadDataName;
    $this->inputFormName = $inputFormName;
}



  $request, $directory, $uploadDataName, $inputFormName

public function handle()
{
        //vars
        $request = new Request;
        dd($request->file());
        $name = $this->request->file($this->inputFormName)->getClientOriginalName();    // 'file' z.B





         $validate = Validator::make($this->request->all(),
         [
             $this->inputFormName => "required|max:1000"
         ] );


         if ( $validate->fails() )
         {
             return response()->json('file.prop.error');     // JSON response!
         }





     // get client-data Name
     if ($name !== $this->uploadDataName)
     {
         return response()->json('file.name.error');     // JSON response!
     }

     $this->request->file($this->inputFormName)->storeAs($this->directory, $name) ;

     //event(new Event_Data_Upload_successfull( SupportController::getAuthUser(), $uploadDataName, $directory ) );
}
```

The Controller...

```
dispatch( new File_Upload('name', 'name.csv', 'file') );

    return redirect('/');
```

In SYNC mode that code works 100% fine.

Comment: Your question seems confusing, and can you include your whole job code and how you dispatch it

Comment: @mastaars I believe either you should pass the request object OR path of the uploaded file to the job. Because from the job it can't access the request object and its data.